# Select and delete data points in plotly dash 3d scatter

Tags: python, plotly-dash, scatter3d

I am trying to add interactivity to a plotly 3d scatter plot which I am hosting using dash.  My question contains two related parts:

(i)  I would like to manually select points in my 3d scatter and change the selected points' colour to red.  Selection should include click event and selection event.

(ii)  I would like to be able to delete these points from the plot on pressing of a key e.g. 'delete' key.

Part (i) is similar to an example in the plotly guide https://plot.ly/python/click-events/, however, on_click is not available as a method for 3d scatter charts.

I have been attempting to use FigureWidget as that apparently provides methods to capture clicks and selections, but after 2 days I am struggling to make headway.

Example data (copy below to clipboard and run df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=','))

```
id,x_val,z_val,y_val
a,11.313449728149418,0.13039110880256777,0.5386387766748618
b,11.321463427315383,0.2360697833061771,1.32441455152796
c,10.127132005050942,0.23085014016641864,1.0961116175427044
d,11.639819269465233,0.0958798324712593,0.6506370305953094
e,8.892696370438149,0.08223988244819926,0.6440321391968353
f,6.711586646011124,0.3657515974938044,
g,7.095030650760687,,0.5723062047617504
h,6.4523124528415,,1.293852184258803
i,7.165105300812886,0.4151365420301895,-0.5920674079031845
j,7.480703395137295,0.14284429977557123,1.0600936940126982
k,5.570775744372319,,
l,4.358946555449826,,
```

I have example code below which I hope is almost there (but not quite). The idea is that 'handle_click' should capture click events.  I should also handle 'selection' events, although I am not sure how to do this as 3d scatter plot does not provide a selection box or lassoo tool.  With the callback, I'm not even sure how to initiate, as there is no clickData/selectionData event with 3d scatterplot that I can utilize (so  `[Input('subindustry-dropdown', 'value')])` is incorrect and note that subindustry-dropdown is not something that I have provided in the example, but I select my ids from a dropdown which returns a subindustry value in my development version.  )

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.css.append_css({
    "external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"
})

app.layout = html.Div([html.Div(id = '3d-scatter'),
])


# Calculate and store data
@app.callback(Output('3d-scatter', 'children'),
               [Input('subindustry-dropdown', 'value')])
def chart_3d():          
    f = go.FigureWidget(px.scatter_3d(df, x = 'x_val', y = 'y_val', z = 'z_val', hover_name = 'company_nm'))

    f.layout.clickmode = 'event+select'
    f.data[0].on_click(handle_click) # if click, then update point/df.      

    return dcc.Graph(id = '3d_scat', figure=f)

def handle_click(trace, points, selector):
    c = list(f.data[0].marker.color)
    s = list(f.data[0].marker.size)
    for i in points.point_inds:
        c[i] = '#bae2be'
        s[i] = 20
        with f.batch_update():
            f.data[0].marker.color = c
            f.data[0].marker.size = s
    return f.data[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution which allows:

- selecting points by clicking individually
- delete selected points by pressing html button
- clear selection by pressing html button

according to this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3511) selecting multiple points in a 3d plot is currently not supported

(The use of FigureWidget does not seem to make a difference, so I removed it)

```
import dash
import plotly.express as px
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import json

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.css.append_css({
    "external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"
})



import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x_val','z_val','y_val'])
df.loc['a'] = [11.313449728149418,0.13039110880256777,0.5386387766748618]
df.loc['b'] = [11.321463427315383,0.2360697833061771,1.32441455152796]
df.loc['c'] = [10.127132005050942,0.23085014016641864,1.0961116175427044]
df.loc['d'] = [11.639819269465233,0.0958798324712593,0.6506370305953094]
df.loc['e'] = [8.892696370438149,0.08223988244819926,0.6440321391968353]
df.loc['f'] = [6.711586646011124,0.3657515974938044,0]
df.loc['g'] = [7.095030650760687,0,0.5723062047617504]
df.loc['h'] = [6.4523124528415,0,1.293852184258803]
df.loc['i'] = [7.165105300812886,0.4151365420301895,-0.5920674079031845]
df.loc['j'] = [7.480703395137295,0.14284429977557123,1.0600936940126982]
df.loc['k'] = [5.570775744372319,0,0]
df.loc['l'] = [4.358946555449826,0,0]

def create_figure(skip_points=[]):
    dfs = df.drop(skip_points)
    return px.scatter_3d(dfs, x = 'x_val', y = 'y_val', z = 'z_val')
f= create_figure()

app.layout = html.Div([html.Button('Delete', id='delete'),
                    html.Button('Clear Selection', id='clear'),
                    dcc.Graph(id = '3d_scat', figure=f),
                    html.Div('selected:'),
                    html.Div(id='selected_points'), #, style={'display': 'none'})),
                    html.Div('deleted:'),
                    html.Div(id='deleted_points') #, style={'display': 'none'}))
])

@app.callback(Output('deleted_points', 'children'),
            [Input('delete', 'n_clicks')],
            [State('selected_points', 'children'),
            State('deleted_points', 'children')])
def delete_points(n_clicks, selected_points, delete_points):
    print('n_clicks:',n_clicks)
    if selected_points:
        selected_points = json.loads(selected_points)
    else:
        selected_points = []

    if delete_points:
        deleted_points = json.loads(delete_points)
    else:
        deleted_points = []
    ns = [p['pointNumber'] for p in selected_points]
    new_indices = [df.index[n] for n in ns if df.index[n] not in deleted_points]
    print('new',new_indices)
    deleted_points.extend(new_indices)
    return json.dumps(deleted_points)



@app.callback(Output('selected_points', 'children'),
            [Input('3d_scat', 'clickData'),
                Input('deleted_points', 'children'),
                Input('clear', 'n_clicks')],
            [State('selected_points', 'children')])
def select_point(clickData, deleted_points, clear_clicked, selected_points):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    ids = [c['prop_id'] for c in ctx.triggered]

    if selected_points:
        results = json.loads(selected_points)
    else:
        results = []


    if '3d_scat.clickData' in ids:
        if clickData:
            for p in clickData['points']:
                if p not in results:
                    results.append(p)
    if 'deleted_points.children' in ids or  'clear.n_clicks' in ids:
        results = []
    results = json.dumps(results)
    return results

@app.callback(Output('3d_scat', 'figure'),
            [Input('selected_points', 'children'),
            Input('deleted_points', 'children')],
            [State('deleted_points', 'children')])
def chart_3d( selected_points, deleted_points_input, deleted_points_state):
    global f
    deleted_points = json.loads(deleted_points_state) if deleted_points_state else []
    f = create_figure(deleted_points)

    selected_points = json.loads(selected_points) if selected_points else []
    if selected_points:
        f.add_trace(
            go.Scatter3d(
                mode='markers',
                x=[p['x'] for p in selected_points],
                y=[p['y'] for p in selected_points],
                z=[p['z'] for p in selected_points],
                marker=dict(
                    color='red',
                    size=5,
                    line=dict(
                        color='red',
                        width=2
                    )
                ),
                showlegend=False
            )
        )

    return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any idea how to select multiple points at once?  there is no box/lassoo selection available, unlike in the dash 2d scatter plots.

Comment: Thanks Carl :) my first bounty! according to the link I also posted box/lasso is not supported by 3d... what appeared to me later you could do is remove points in a circular/box shaped volume around a (or serveral) selected point(s) with a function that you trigger with say another html button...