# Click events in python plotly-dash Scatterpolar plot

Tags: python, onclick, plotly-dash, ipywidgets

I'd like to create two web pages which contain iframed plotly-dash graphs. I'd like to implement click events of the first graph to redirect to the other page (with more info about that specific datum)

I followed [this](https://plotly.com/python/click-events/) guide, but the **click event is not triggered** in my setup even when I installed ipywidgets, node.js and plotlywidgets extension to the python venv I'm running it in. There is a note in the exaple above:

> Note: Callbacks will only be triggered when the trace belongs to a
> instance of plotly.graph_objs.FigureWidget and it is displayed in an
> ipywidget context. Callbacks will not be triggered on figures
> that are displayed using plot/iplot.

The example is using the `FigureWidget` and I'm drawing it by passing the figure to `dcc.Graph` which should be the same as `fig.show()`. The whole code looks like this

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

fig = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers')])

scatter = fig.data[0]
colors = ['#a3a7e4'] * 100
scatter.marker.color = colors
scatter.marker.size = [10] * 100
fig.layout.hovermode = 'closest'


# create our callback function
def update_point(trace, points, selector):
    c = list(scatter.marker.color)
    s = list(scatter.marker.size)
    for i in points.point_inds:
        c[i] = '#bae2be'
        s[i] = 20
        with fig.batch_update():
            scatter.marker.color = c
            scatter.marker.size = s


scatter.on_click(update_point)

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
]) 

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I don't know how to make/be sure that it is displayed in ipywidget context though.

I'm aware of a workaround like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310199/select-and-delete-data-points-in-plotly-dash-3d-scatter) with `layout.clickmode = select` and a separate button, but I'd like to make the figure's `on_click()` events working.

Could someone please help me to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this part of the documentation:

> in an ipywidget context

It means that this will only work in a jupyter notebook for example.

If you wish to have this kind of graph interaction when using dash, you should use the `dcc.Graph` attributes to fire your callbacks (`hoverData`, `clickData`, `selectedData`, `relayoutData`).

See more here: [Interactive Visualizations](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing)